# Typescript cant find module

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I'm trying to import a module with Typescript on Visual Studio 2019.

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
(<any>window).Highcharts = Highcharts;
```

Results in:

> Error TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'highcharts'.
>   Error TS2307  Build:Cannot find module
>   '../node_modules/highcharts'.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

This is my packages.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "del": "5.1.0",
    "highcharts": "8.0.0"
  }
}
```

If I look under dependencies => npm, highcharts is there. If I look in my node_modules folder, highcharts is there.

What am I missing? I'm new to using modules in typescript but everything I find on google seems to look like my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to highcharts readme you need to import it something like this

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

then you need to update your `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/*.src.js": [
        "node_modules/highcharts/*.src"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

check this
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#typescript--umd

Comment: Check updated answer and check the reference for more details

Comment: Hmm , closer. Now I get `highcharts" has no default export` as an error, but it finds it at least.

Comment: Oh wait, I missed esModuleInterop and allowsyntheticDefaultImports. Added both and now it works. Thanks!